# PowerBI - Actual & Planned Dates on Same X Axis

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

In Excel you can use a clustered column chart buckets Actual shipment dates within their respective Planned shipment date. See attached image. I would like to know if this is possible in PowerBI?
[excel clustered column chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WsPAk.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically yes - you can add two date columns to the Axis well, then use the Expand button to show one nested inside the other.

But the presentation of the X-axis labels is awful and cant be customized. It will show the dates from the two levels side-by-side, e.g. your first bar would appear as:

05/04/2021 05/05/2021

Comment: thank you for your response. I tried that out and you're correct, it looks pretty rough. Any thoughts on an alternate visual that would help paint the same story?

Comment: I'd try a matrix, with the dates on rows vs columns. The data should cluster along the diagonal.